# Error retrieving json data in IE7 using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I've recently been asked to try and fix an app built in angularjs to work in IE7. The main issue seems to be retrieving data from the server.

The following example code works on all browsers > IE7

```
    $scope.getEntity = function (id, callback) {
        $http.get('/views/entities/' + id).
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.entity = data;
                callback();
            }).
            error(function(data) {
                $window.location.href = '/error';
            });
    };
```

When this fires in IE7 it always ends up throwing an error with an undefined data parameter and redirects to the error page.

Any ideas why this would be happening? It's only isolated to IE7 as it works fine in all other browsers.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/guide/ie

Comment: @estus Thanks I have been through that document. Angular seems to be working ok but when I call one of our service endpoints it fails for some reason. Only in IE7.

Comment: And you checked the section regarding JSON.stringify, didn't you? Nobody except you knows what your exact setup is. You may consider recreating the issue in plunker and sharing it, it is not something that can be solved blindly.

Comment: @estus Your absolutely right. I did add the polyfill script but I removed it as I didn't think it worked. Added it back in and it works now. Happy to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [1.2.x manual](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/guide/ie) says,

> To make your Angular application work on IE please make sure that:
>
> You polyfill JSON.stringify for IE7 and below. You can use JSON2 or JSON3 polyfills for this.

Polyfills may be missed in the places where `JSON` methods should be obviously called (like JSON AJAX requests).